# Is python/django less problamatic to manage compared to rails?

Tags: hosting, python, django, ruby-on-rails

Is managing a python/django server generally easier/trouble free when compared to a ruby/rails app?

Comment: Might be easier to answer if you specify what exactly you find troublesome about managing rails apps.

Answer (score 1):

As with all things software related, each programmer/administrator is different and will find certain methodologies easier than others. Rails people will tell you it's the best, and Django people will tell you it's the best.

The answer to your question will always be a subjective opinion.